# Drop Rows in First Df column, on condition based on another Df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop some rows from the main df using a condition.
The main purpose is, I need to drop the rows of all latitude and longitude that are outside a perimeter (another df with less latitude and longitude values).
I tried with this code with no success, giving me this error: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
for x in df_limit['Latitude']:
if (x > incidents_locations['Latitude']):
   df_dropped=incidents_locations.drop(incidents_locations[incidents_locations.Latitude].index)
```

Of course, the same process has to be performed for the longitude columns.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you give a example of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to drop rows based on the value of `x`. For this, you can use the following snippet:

```py
for x in df_limit['Latitude']:
       df_dropped=incidents_locations.drop(incidents_locations[x > incidents_locations['Latitude']].index)
```

Comment: The code snippet you provided me worked perfectly!